# Combined Dynamic RLS works in the desktop not in the PowerBI Service App

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, authorization, row-level-security

I created dynamic RLS in my report in PowerBI desktop.
For both the pathfunction (organisational hierachie) as the superuser (columnvalue is 1 for superuser) it works just fine. The combination of the 2 also works great.  But the latter one does not in the powerbi service.
It does not have anything to do with RLS and the workspace reader, contributor etc, nor with the email for the named user. The combined function works in the desktop, but not in the App I created in the PowerBI service. Anyone ever experienced that? Or solved it?
Hope to hear from you.

Regards, Louis

I tested it for every possible RLS for one person with as named user; user = UPN()
I Know for RLS to work, a user needs to have read only permission in the workspace. That's all they have, read